# switching between layouts Blender 2.8 (Mac laptop)

Tags: shortcut

I am new in Blender. I realise that I can not switch between layouts in B2.8 I am following the shortcut ctrl+pageup and can not make it work out. It might be cause I do not have a pageup button. Did anyone experienced this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go under preferences
- select input
- then under keyboard select emulate keyboard

[image]